# Ubuntu mobaxterm that has drag and drop

Tags: 16.04, ssh, remote-access

I am using my pc to connect to the server with GPUs and need to do a lot of transfers. I used mobaxterm when on Windows. It has drag and drop which is very convenient. Is there a similar tool on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

A list of Linux alternatives to [Mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) is found at https://alternativeto.net/software/mobaxterm/?platform=linux but you will need to think about what features are essential vs important vs nice to have, then sift through what you find there. I'd also suggest you scratch off the list any which are discontinued, or no longer supported.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Termius for SSH but this is not Look like a Mobaxterm.
But it's Providing many Features like Authentication Key, you can Create Group of Host, SFTP, Key Store Etc.

Comment: Hey Mahesh Dabhi! Please make sure that your answer is detailed.

Comment: You can use Termius for SSH but this is not Look like a Mobaxterm. But it's Providing many Features like Authentication Key, you can Create Group of Host, SFTP, Key Store Etc.
@technastic_tc